# How to get company's Active Directory data to display on a razor view(webgrid)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, active-directory

I need to build a simple asp.net mvc web apps to display the detailed data from Active Directory and show it in a webgrid feature , is that possible? I appreciate if anybody can provide any good examples, thanks in advance.

I found this example: http://www.dotnetcodesg.com/Article/UploadFile/2/223/Get%20List%20of%20Active%20Directory%20Users%20in%20ASP.NET%20Csharp.aspx

but when I execute the codes, the program stopped on this line of code:

```
MembershipUser myUser = Membership.GetAllUsers()[searchResult...
```

I got error : "Unable to connect to SQL Server database. "

The codes stopped on :

```
MembershipUser myUser = Membership.GetAllUsers()[searchResult.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString()];
```

It seems I need to connect Membership database, do I have to connect membership database in order to get all employee data?

I only want to get all employee information such as : name, ID, email, phone , ,, and display them in a view (better in webgrid or other format easy to read).

```
I tried these codes :
DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP://company.domin);
```

//  DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection) { Filter =   ("(objectClass=user)") };

```
 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();            

// search.CacheResults = true;             

search.SearchRoot = myLdapConnection;             

search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;            

SearchResultCollection allResults = search.FindAll();

        DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable();

        resultsTable.Columns.Add("sAMAccountName");
```

.....

Basically, I added the data to a datatable and show them in a razor view,  I got the data and displayed them on the razor view, but the data is not complete data, some employee information is missing, can anybody tell me what is wrong with my codes for the missing data? there must be something wrong with the codes which get the partial data. What I want to get is complete data in my company's Active Directory which includes all employee's name and group name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The database error message suggests that your site is configured for Forms Authentication. You need to set the authentication mode to Windows in your web.config file to use Active directory.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Yes, in my webconfig file, it is setup like that, I just checked it again.